Docker for Debian on a VMware ESXi VM frequently crashes
About a month ago I installed the latest version of Docker on Debian 12 on a VMware ESXi 8.0U2 virtual machine (latest vSphere version).
I tried to get VNC running but other priorities took over, so for now I'm just accessing the VM via VMware Remote Console, using Gnome.
It has the latest version of VMware Tools installed:
$ sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
open-vm-tools is already the newest version (2:12.2.0-1+deb12u2).
open-vm-tools-desktop is already the newest version (2:12.2.0-1+deb12u2).

There is only ever 1 single container running at the same time. I regularly do docker image prune -f and docker system prune
Whenever the VM is running "on it's own" (without me connected to it via Remote Console on Gnome), it runs like a champ, and never ever goes down.
Whenever I am accessing the VM and doing stuff, it randomly hangs, and my "fix" is to reboot the VM. Trying to access the nginx server running on the container from another machine whilst it is hanging results in our reverse-proxy returning Error 503 Service Unavailable - No server is available to handle this request.
The entire Debian Docker host VM totally locks up when it does this and doesn't let me click/type and the screen freezes. I am not doing anything overly demanding. I am usually just editing a file in nano in the Terminal or something.
Sometimes I'm doing nothing whatsoever on the VM, I am simply just connected to it via VMware Remote Console - and it will go down. It does it at random intervals, but I usually get about an hour or 2 before it crashes, but this seems to change at random, sometimes I get a few hours - lately I'm getting less time before it crashes.
If I wait and don't reboot the VM then Remote Console does eventually come back to life after 5-10 minutes, the screen unfreezes, and I can give input again. The Docker daemon dies. I am not using Docker Deskop. It is installed but it is not set to startup automatically on boot/login.
Sometimes there are no  containers running when it crashes. The container that I do use on there is a very simple webserver that only I access.
Sometimes (but not always) even issuing a Reboot to the VM from within VMware Remote Console while the VM is hanging won't work the 1st time (but it usually works the 2nd time):

Within vSphere when the VM is hanging I am [sometimes?] seeing the CPU sustaining 100% usage! I have reduced the CPU cores from 4 to 2 as it was causing very high CPU consumption on the VMware host server with a 6c 12t Xeon E5-1650V3. The VM has 8GB RAM.
I have no problems with any of my other (Linux, FreeBSD & Windows) non-Docker VMs.
Where do I begin trying to troubleshoot this please?
My feeling is that this is either VMware Tools or Gnome related. Whenever I'm running a Dockerfile build (but also whilst doing nothing sometimes), I have noticed that these processes often consume very high CPU:

qemu-system-x86_64

This one also has high disk reads/writes, which I guess is normal when building
Hovering over the process in System Monitor shows it is Docker-related:



gnome-shell
docker-scout
com.docker.backend

Often the build will complete successfully, but those processes still remain using high CPU for a little while afterwards - sometimes causing a crash (when nothing is building any more).
I am not adverse to trying something on a brand new install of Debian, but I'm not convinced it will help if I change nothing else in my setup.

Uninstall all the desktop stuff and see if the problem persists. Graphical interfaces have no place on a server, it's just a waste of resources.

if you can have a shell elsewhere, profiling with perf might give an idea of what is keeping the CPU busy... Removing open-vm-tools might also give an indication if that is involved... (if it completely hangs, someone that know more what they are doing might get some clues from a memory dump, but that is a lot harder than checking from a running box...)

When it “crashes” does it start to slow down before it actually crashes- or does it just suddenly crash?

Damn- that sounds annoying and hard to troubleshoot!
Could you try running a resource monitoring program that records live results and saves them to a stable hard drive partition for further analysis?

qemu-system-x86_64 usually uses kvm. So is that to run a VM-in-a-VM? Maybe some settings for running a VM inside a VM are not correct on the ESX side, triggering a bug on the (VMware) VM? Also do you really need to run a VM inside a VM? Looks like that's what would happen if you install "Docker Desktop" instead of plain "docker.io".

Then what's the role of qemu-system-x86_64? There shouldn't be any need for it.

Sorry but I won't read the PDF. It has to be in the question. Also I already wrote what I could write and suspect: useless VM-in-a-VM.  If you reinstall a new system, don't follow your PDF. Just run apt-get install docker.io (on a new system only. And you can care later for having the brand latest/shiniest upstream version).

But you never replied to my former comment "Then what's the role of qemu-system-x86_64?". Because it is NOT a Docker thing.

My last comment: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/ . Note how there's written "Docker Desktop on Linux runs a Virtual Machine (VM)". "Docker Desktop" is for a desktop. It must not be installed on a server.

OP here.
Our setup is: physical box runs ESXi > has a VM for Debian/Docker > has a container for nginx.
I originally misunderstood @GeraldSchneider's comment - I thought he meant to uninstall Gnome Desktop (maybe he did too), but in fact uninstalling Docker Desktop makes total sense now, in hindsight.
Thanks goes to @AB's comments for pointing out that:

Two distinct installation options exist: Docker Desktop + Docker Engine
Unlike Docker Engine, Docker Desktop runs inside a VM via QEMU within the Debian VM, causing nested virtualisation - which causes the host VM to crash frequently!

I abandoned the original install and reinstalled Debian from scratch, following these guides:

Docker Docs > Install Docker Engine on Debian
Docker Docs > Linux Post-Installation

Specifically, configuring the default logging driver



I also switched to KDE, now that Gnome-related things aren't needed by Docker Desktop. Only time will tell, but it seems to be a lot snappier in response times and no crashes (yet)!! Edit 8 months later: it’s been performing like a dream ever since! 
See also (but do NOT follow the guides):

Docker Docs > Install Docker Desktop on Linux - which states in several places:

Docker Desktop on Linux runs a Virtual Machine (VM)


Docker Docs > FAQs for Docker Desktop for Linux > Why does Docker Desktop for Linux run a VM?
Docker Docs > Install Docker Desktop on Debian

